# Splitting an UIImage in two different UIimageviews in CoreGraphics-iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

**Problem:** I have an three UIImageViews. One has an `UIImage` and the other two are namely - leftImageView & rightImageView. The leftImageView has the left half of the image and the right one has the other. I am trying to achieve this using Coregraphics, i.e. drawing an image in the two imageviews.

But the right imageview isn't showing up. Refer to the code below:

```
UIImage *image = imgView.image;
CGSize sz = [image size];
CGRect leftRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.frame.size.width/2, imgView.frame.size.height);
CGRect rightRect = CGRectMake(imgView.frame.size.width/2, 0, imgView.frame.size.width/2, imgView.frame.size.height);

CGImageRef leftReference =  CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], leftRect);
CGImageRef rightReference = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rightRect);

// Left Image ...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(leftRect.size.width, leftRect.size.height), NO, 0);
CGContextRef con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(con, leftRect,flip(leftReference));

imgViewLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.view addSubview:imgViewLeft];


// Right Image ...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(rightRect.size.width, rightRect.size.height), NO, 0);
con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(con, rightRect,flip(rightReference));

imgViewRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


[self.view addSubview:imgViewRight];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the following code part.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.png"]; // You can change this line.
BOOL isLeft = YES; // You can change this variable(isLeft = YES : left piece, NO : right piece).

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(image.size.width / 2, image.size.height));  

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  

if (isLeft)
     CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);
else
     CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(- image.size.width / 2, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;
```

I couldn't launch this code now, but I think that my code is almost correct. Please try this.

**Edit :**

In your code :

```
// Right Image ...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(rightRect.size.width, rightRect.size.height), NO, 0);
con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(con, rightRect,flip(rightReference));

imgViewRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

There is a wrong part in the third line :

```
 CGContextDrawImage(con, rightRect,flip(rightReference));
```

It should be

```
 CGContextDrawImage(con, leftRect,flip(rightReference));
```

Comment: Dear @Jinx , thanks for the help but i figured it out that in the method:
`void CGContextDrawImage(CGContextRef c, CGRect rect,
    CGImageRef image)` 
I was providing rect as rightRect whose co-ordinates start at the second half of the image. I was to provide leftRect in it.